# Optimize a Django query where it uses prefetch_related on a select_related

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize a Django query. I have an queryset that contains a foreign key to `exercises`. That table makes `ManyToMany` references to a number of other tables. If selecting `exercises`, I'd use `prefetch_related` to include them in the query, but I can't figure out how to do that in this case, since I'm doing it from a different table. Currently, it's being selected as

```
super().get_queryset(request).select_related('exercise').prefetch_related('exercise__equipments', 'exercise__injuries')
```

But I can't figure out how to attach `prefetch_related` to that. Looking at SO, I found a solution that led me to this:

```
return super().get_queryset(request).select_related(
    Prefetch(
        'exercise',
        queryset=Exercise.objects.prefetch_related('equipments', 'inuries')
    )
)
```

But it fails with `'Prefetch' object has no attribute 'split'`, which I traced through the source, and it looks like `select_related` can't work with `Prefetch`.

EDIT: More info:

- I'm trying to optimize an admin page with a `SortableStackedInline`
- The starting model is Template

```
class Template(SortableMixin):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey('Exercise', models.CASCADE)

class Exercise(models.Model):
    equipments = models.ManyToManyField('Equipment', blank=True, through='ExerciseEquipment')
    injuries = models.ManyToManyField('Injury', blank=True, through='ExerciseInjury')
```

The ultimate goal is to optimize the query from Template through Equipment/Injury

Comment: can you provide a models.py

Comment: @bazzuk123 Added them.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to optimize query using combination of select_related and prefetch_related.

`Prefetch` should be used with `prefetch_related` not `select_related`.

I'm not sure cuz I didn't test it, try this one.

**- Here's code:**

```
prefetch1 = Prefetch(
    "exercise__equipments",
    queryset=Equipment.objects.all(), ----------------------------------- [2]
    to_attr="prefetch_equipments_set"
) ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [1]

prefetch2 = Prefetch(
    "exercise__injuries",
    queryset=Injury.objects.all(),    ----------------------------------- [2]
    to_attr="prefetch_injuries_set"
) ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [1]

queryset = Template.objects.all()  -------------------------------------- [2]
queryset = queryset.select_related("exercise")  ------------------------- [3]
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(prefetch1, prefetch2)  ------------- [4]
```

- `[1]` - `Prefetch` object
- `[2]` - you can add `filter` or `order_by` whatever.
- `[3]` - optimize query using `select_related`
- `[4]` - optimize query using `prefetch_related`, `[1]`

**- How to use:**

- get equipments from Template(id=1)

```
queryset.get(id=1).exercise.prefetch_equipments_set
```

- get injuries from Template(id=1)

```
queryset.get(id=1).exercise.prefetch_injuries_set
```

Comment: So unfortunately, it didn't work, but it may also be because of how it's being used. We're not calling the queryset directly, rather it's being used in an admin page, so being called for us. I removed the `to_attr` so it'd map to the base attr, but still as many queries as before :/

Comment: Which data you want to get, ultimately?

Comment: I want to optimize the query that ends up being able to get all the data in a single query. Right now, as it's an admin page, makes dozens of calls, which obviously takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help. Look how i navigate through ForeignKeys
My goal is to get Resume that has SkillName="DJANGO"

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    CreationDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    

class Skill(models.Model):
    SkillName = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ResumeSkill(models.Model):
    Resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Resume --> ResumeSkill.Skill --> Skill.SkillName

notice how django handles cammel cases

```
Resume.objects.filter(resumeskill__Skill__SkillName="DJANGO")
```

Comment: This isn't about filtering; I know how to do that. I'm trying to figure out how to optimize the query. Usually it'd be with `select_related` or `prefetch_related`, but the camel case doesn't work here for `prefetch_related`. I'll update the question again.